# Ajax success function not working on the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

**Aim**: Continue to display any form validation errors through json callback

**Problem**: When I submit on the form with invalid input it shows an error message in a div element. If all inputs are valid it will process the ajax request and show a success message in a div element. After which, the form resets but the modal remain open. When I try to again validate the input in doesn't show any error message. When I try to test the valid input still the same no message shown.

**In short**: Ajax success function not working on the second time.

Here's my code:

Bootstrap Modal (where my form inputs placed)

```
<div class="modal fade" id='frmModal'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                <h4 class='title'>Add new data</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo form_open('Employee/save',array('id'=>'frm', 'class'=>'form-horizontal')); ?>
                <div id="message"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for='fname' class='col-md-3 control-label'>First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" name="fname" id='fname' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name...'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='lname' class='col-md-3 control-label'>Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" name="lname" id='lname' class='form-control' placeholder='Last Name...'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='age' class='col-md-3 control-label'>Age:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" name="age" id='age' class='form-control' placeholder='Age...'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary action" type='submit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></i> Save Data</button>
                    </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).on('submit','#frm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#frm');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors) {
                    $('#message').html(data.errors).addClass('alert alert-danger');
                }
            } else {
                 reloadData();

                $('#message').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span> " + data.message).removeClass('alert alert-danger').addClass('alert alert-success');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }, 3000);
               $('#frm')[0].reset();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

CodeIgniter Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('age','Age', 'trim|numeric|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE)
    {
        $info['success'] = false;
        $info['errors'] = validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $info['success'] = true;
        $data = array(
                    "firstname" => $this->input->post('fname'),
                    "lastname" => $this->input->post('lname'),
                    "age" => $this->input->post('age'),
                      );
        $this->Employee_model->save('ci_table', $data);
        $info['message'] = 'Successfully saved data';
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($info));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand... The form still works but the messages do not appear? If so then try the below...

You are removing the #message element instead of clearing it... try:

```
 $("#message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
                    $(this).empty();
```

This way you are emptying the #message element instead of removing it completely..

Comment: it's not working. Error message still not showing up. There's a json response but I wonder why it is not showing up on the error message div element

Comment: Are you saying, even on the first run through (with error) you are not getting any message at all? if so I would add a console.log(data) in both success and failure areas and ensure the object is coming through as you expect it to...

Comment: No, I mean the second time around the error message or success message is not showing

Comment: Is #message still in the DOM after the first run?

Comment: Hello with your suggested $(this).empty() the #message is in the DOM however when I click on the button nothing happens even though there is a json response.